# interrupting a loop in python without stopping a function whenever I want

Tags: python, loops, break

Before I get to the point, here is my sample code:

```
x = 0
while x < 50000000:
    x += 1
    print(x)

print("Calculation done")
```

As you can see, this code will run for a long period of time.
I want to interrupt this 'while loop' without arising any error and get the last print "Calculation done"

Is there any way for it?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `break`?

Comment: I do not know when I will want it to stop. Other words, it won't have any condition to stop it.

Comment: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your loop in a `try-except`:

```
try:
    x = 0
    while x < 50000000:
        x += 1
        print(x)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
print("Calculation done")
```

Edit: you would stop this with `^C`